# How to put a sleep function while deciding in confirm box

Tags: javascript, html, time, sleep, user-experience

I wanted to put to sleep "timer" function till someone decides if he want to stay or leave my site after clicking "exit" button so the time in the background is frozen. But if he decides to stay, timer function should go on. I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me? Thanks for all advices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="exit();">exit</button>
    <p id="seconds">30</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;



        function timer () {
            clearInterval(clock);
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            clock = setInterval(function() {
                var seconds = Math.round(30 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
                if (seconds >= 0)
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
                else 
                    clearInterval(clock);



                    if (seconds==0)     document.getElementById("fotka").innerHTML='<img src="mopsik.jpg"/>';




            }, 1000);
        }

        function exit(){

var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
if (result == true) {
window.location.href="www.something.com";
}
else {

}
}

        timer();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval` is executing the function every X time, you can clear the interval in the exit function, and run the function again if the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

Just when the user click on exit, clear the interval (meaning that he won't count the seconds anymore), if the result false, start the interval again.

```
var clock;
var start;

function StartTimer () {
  if (clock) {
    clearInterval(clock);
  }
  start = new Date().getTime();
  startInterval();
}

function startInterval() {

  clock = setInterval(function() {
    var seconds = Math.round(30 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);

    if (seconds >= 0) {
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
    } else{
      clearInterval(clock);
    }

    if (seconds==0)
      document.getElementById("fotka").innerHTML='<img src="mopsik.jpg"/>';

  }, 1000);

}

function exit() {

  clearInterval(clock);
  var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");

  if (result == true) {
    window.location.href="www.something.com";
  } else {
    startInterval();
  }
}
```